# Install cakePHP 3.0 with composer issue

Tags: php, cakephp, installation, composer-php

I used command to install new CakePHP project:

> composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app project-name

but it always display this error:

> ```
> [RuntimeException]
>   Could not scan for classes inside "database/seeds" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder
> ```

Picture attached[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Noted that my PHP -v : 

PHP 7.1.9 (cli) (built: Aug 30 2017 18:34:46) ( ZTS MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies

Comment: `database/seeds` sounds like Laravel...

Comment: Try to remove the `vendor` dir and run `composer self-update` and `composer install` afterwards.